# oracle ojdbc7 issue - camel-sql component failed to execute queries after upgrading to ojdbc7 driver

Tags: oracle, apache-camel, jbossfuse, ojdbc

Post upgrading ojdbc driver to `ojdbc7`, `camel-sql` component started creating issues when executed queries with named parameters.

Provided the simple SQL query which failed during the execution. Not all the queries are failing but only few of them.

```
SELECT some_id 
  FROM app_schema.app_store_table 
 WHERE store_id = :#storeId 
   AND source = :#source;
```

On Database side verified that the username has access to the object with app_schema and also tried creating a `PUBLIC` synonym, but no luck.

Based on my understanding, it fails while trying to get the parameter count in `SqlProducer.java` → `process()` → `execute()` → `ps.getParameterMetaData()`

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(statementCreator, new PreparedStatementCallback<Map<?, ?>>() {
    public Map<?, ?> doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
       int expected = parametersCount > 0 ? parametersCount : ps.getParameterMetaData().getParameterCount();
       ...
```

Further debugging found the following error from `ojdbc7` driver. It confirms that the `ojdbc7` driver failed to parse the query correctly. In the below example, the "`.`" ([DOT]) between `schema_name` and `table_name` is replaced by ojdbc driver before execution.

```
Aug 30, 2017 9:06:57 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection isValid
FINE: 19C71BE Exit [17.696372ms]
Aug 30, 2017 9:06:57 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection prepareStatement
FINE: 19C71BE Public Enter: "**SELECT some_id FROM app_schema.app_store_table WHERE store_id = ? and source = ?**"
Aug 30, 2017 9:06:57 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection prepareStatement
FINE: 19C71BE Return: oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@c2c269
Aug 30, 2017 9:06:57 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection prepareStatement
FINE: 19C71BE Exit [226.482362ms]
Aug 30, 2017 9:06:57 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection prepareStatement
FINE: 19C71BE Public Enter: "***SELECT store_id, source FROM app_schemaapp_store_table***" <-- .[DOT] between schema_name and table_name is replaced by the driver which results in this error. 
Aug 30, 2017 9:06:57 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection prepareStatement
FINE: 19C71BE Return: oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@e1e592
Aug 30, 2017 9:06:57 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection prepareStatement
FINE: 19C71BE Exit [0.413825ms]
Aug 30, 2017 9:06:57 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement getMetaData
FINE: E1E592 Public Enter: 
Aug 30, 2017 9:06:57 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer processError
SEVERE: CD5A42 Throwing SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

This can be replicated easily using the following command

```
-- example for .[DOT] getting replaced between schema_name and table_name. Refer Parameter SQL.
C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\ojdbc\oracle>java -cp ojdbc7_g-12.1.0.2.jar oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaDataParser "*SELECT some_id FROM app_schema.app_store_table WHERE store_id = ? and source = ?*"
SQL:SELECT some_id FROM app_schema.app_store_table WHERE store_id = :1  and source = :2
  SqlKind:SELECT, Parameter Count=2
  Parameter SQL: ***SELECT store_id, source FROM app_schemaapp_store_table***
-- example for invalid parsing of the query. Refer Parameter SQL. 
C:\Users\vm\ojdbc\oracle>java -cp ojdbc7_g-12.1.0.2.jar oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaDataParser "*SELECT f_some_id FROM app_store_table WHERE f_store_id = ? and f_source = ?*"
SQL:SELECT f_some_id FROM app_store_table WHERE f_store_id = :1  and f_source = :2
  SqlKind:SELECT, Parameter Count=2
  Parameter SQL: ***SELECT f, f FROM app_store_table***
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1018)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Odscrarr.doODNY(T4C8Odscrarr.java:96)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:717)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.describe(OracleStatement.java:4404)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetMetaData.<init>(OracleResultSetMetaData.java:52)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getResultSetMetaData(OracleStatement.java:4387)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.getMetaData(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5581)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.getMetaData(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1509)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaData.getParameterMetaData(OracleParameterMetaData.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(OraclePreparedStatement.java:12861)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.getParameterMetaData(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1551)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:266)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:266)
at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer$2.doInPreparedStatement(SqlProducer.java:92)
at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer$2.doInPreparedStatement(SqlProducer.java:90)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
... 29 more
```

The same component worked well with ojdbc6.

Environment Details:

```
-Camel : 2.15.1.redhat-621166  
-Fuse  : 6.2.1
-OJDBC : ojdbc7 (12.1.0.2)
```

### Additonal Dependecies.

```
-commons-dbcp2 (2.1.1)
-commons-pool2 (2.4.2)
-spring-jdbc (3.2.12.RELEASE)
```

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is a JDBC issue since it is causing the problem after upgrade.

Comment: right, just figured it out. ojdbc7 driver is not parsing the query correctly.